# Standard method of upgrading a subscription in Braintree?

Tags: braintree

I am working on an integration for Braintree and trying to adapt the subscriptions to a model which can account for subscriptions which are "upgraded" from one plan to another. I can see that you can change the plan, and then separately update the price. However, this seems less correct than just cancelling a previous subscription and creating a new one.

So in summary, is there a native way to indicate upgrading a subscription or at least a best practice that most would follow for Braintree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work for Braintree.</sub>

I would suggest changing the plan and then updating the price for your business model. Assuming upgrading plans includes an increase in price, you can easily [prorate a subscription](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/manage/#proration) when the price changes in the middle of a billing cycle. In Ruby it would look like this:
​

```
result = Braintree::Subscription.update( 
  "subscription_id_to_update",
  :price => "14.00",
  :plan_id => "new_plan",
  :options => { :prorate_charges => true },
)
```

One use case for canceling and then creating new subscriptions upon upgrade would be if the plan upgrade is on a different billing cycle, e.g. yearly instead of monthly, because you cannot update to a plan with a different billing cycle.
[More information on updating subscriptions](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/manage/#updating-subscriptions).

If you have any additional questions, feel free to reach out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).

Comment: Is there any way to not have to input the new price manually but have it taken directly for the new plan information?

Comment: @RyanPergent seems `price` parameter isn't required: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/subscription/update/ruby#price